# What is the return value for attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:?

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I learned how to set attributes to `NSAttributedStrings`, but I am confused how to retrieve the attribute values after they are set. I have two questions:

1. For example the methods below can be retrieve the attribute values, but what kind of values will it return?
2. Will it return the name of the attribute in `NSString/NSAttributeString`? or return an `NSDictionary`?

Thanks for your advice in advance!

```
attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:
attributesAtIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:
attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:
attribute:atIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:
fontAttributesInRange:
rulerAttributesInRange:
```

Comment: DId u read the documentation ?

Comment: In the documentation, it uses id as return type.... can I compare id?

Comment: If you wanted to read documentation, you'd start at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html which would seemingly answer 1) and 2). I am not so clear what you mean by 3).

Comment: I removed my third question

Comment: You can check this out: http://ios.eezytutorials.com/nsattributedstring-by-example.php#.V2DiV47_Z0c